# Best way to read incremental rows from oracle using java

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

Currently we are polling a database table every 10 seconds and reading the rows that are incremented progressively using a rest end point. Every poll we are reading from beginning. Is there any best way so that we can avoid polling or read records only once.each poll records are read and converted to JSON to give back to console.

Comment: which database do you use? Using e.g. oracle you could invert the control and let the db push new records if you turn your architecture upside down (using jms e.g.). Much cheaper would be to store the max key read on the client (given the key column uses the usual increment) and poll with a query `where keyColumn > max`.

Comment: It’s oracle. Is there any way to handle from rest side

Comment: How can oracle push the data to jms. Please let me know

Comment: I used it longer ago by plsql (so you can trigger it in an sql insert even), here's a [bit of documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/t_jms.htm) and you have java in oracle too, but I have no experience with that.

Comment: Have you looked into [continuous query notification?](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adfns/cqn.html#GUID-373BAF72-3E63-42FE-8BEA-8A2AEFBF1C35)